# How to add and use a tag on jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am trying to add a customTag to jsdoc. I have created a file in the plugins directory like this:

**method.js**

```
exports.defineTags = function(dictionary) {
    dictionary.defineTag("methodHttp", {
        mustHaveValue: true,
        canHaveType: false,
        canHaveName: true,
        onTagged: function(doclet, tag) {
            doclet.methodHttp = tag.value;
        }
    });
};
```

Then I added to my **conf.json**:

```
{
    "tags": {
        "allowUnknownTags": true
    },
    "source": {
        "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc)?$",
        "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
    },
    "plugins": [ "plugins/method" ],
    "templates": {
        "cleverLinks": false,
        "monospaceLinks": false,
        "default": {
            "outputSourceFiles": true
        }
    },
    "jsVersion": 180
}
```

And now I try to get this on my template. I'm on method.tmpl.

I tried:

```
self.find('methodHttp')[0]
data.methodHttp[0]
data.methodHttp
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jsDoc.defineTag` does not support tags with uppercase char...

Though it seems to be a bug in their dictionary!