# documenting side-effects of javascript methods

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, code-structure

I'm trying to improve the documentation of my javascript code, and am following the JSDoc guidelines https://jsdoc.app/.

I can't find how to document an intentional side-effect. For example the following method:

```
/**
  * @description
  *   Paints the object red.
  * @return
*/
Painter.paintItRed = function(someObj){
    someObj.color = "red";
};
```

How do you document the fact that the method acts directly on the passed object? A different example:

```
/**
  * @description
  *   If the user has not setUp a config, show config Modal.
  * @return
*/
User.checkConfig = function(user){
    if(!user.config.valid){
       showConfigModal();
    }
};
```

These are contrived examples and probable "code smells", but that's another issue. I'm looking at some best-practices on how to document such behavior (for good or bad). Something perhaps better than `//IMPORTANT!! This method is dangerous!`

Comment: I don't know one but I'd like it!

Comment: I asked this question a long time ago and looking back at it I'm not sure it's that valuable. If your method is short, with an obvious name, and in a meaningful object/namespace there should not be a lot of confusion about what it's doing. A traditional clue for side-effects has been that a method takes an argument but does not return anything. However if the language always returns the last expression that logic can't be used. So you should rely on a name that clearly shows action `function doSomethingDangerous`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since version 3.6.0, JSDoc has an undocumented `@modifies` tag for exactly this purpose.
See [commit 2f99af8](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/commit/2f99af8fbbfb7f19d9f962c40884a13ce38696da) and [issue 1283](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1283).

---

*Previous answer, included for the reference to adding your own tag.* There is no standardized way of doing this. At least [not in JavaDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36448000/962603), which, to be fair, is what JSDoc is mimicking. There is [an issue](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1283) to add it to JSDoc, by the way, that is actually referencing this question.

If you really want to document this, you can add a custom tag, like you can [for JavaDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7428109/962603). You could use that to add, for example, an `@affects` tag. It could be used as follows.

```
/**
 * @description
 *   Paints the object red.
 * @param someObj
 *   The object to be painted.
 * @affects
 *   someObj.color
 */
Painter.paintItRed = function(someObj) {
    someObj.color = 'red';
};
```

Defining a custom tag in JSDoc [is not hard](https://jsdoc.app/about-plugins.html#tag-definitions), also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14982923/962603).